# like is posting the url with_escaped_fragmet

Tags: facebook-like, social-networking

I've implemented a like widget which it's URL parameter is set to 
"http://www.justanexample.com#!home|mainPage"

the (relevant) meta-tags for this page:

```
&lt;link rel="canonical" href="http://www.justanexample.com"/&gt;

&lt;meta property="og:url" content="http://www.justanexample.com"/&gt;
```

still when a user likes the page and posts the message, the link is:

> "http://www.justanexample.com?_escaped_fragment_=mainPage"

My assumption is as follows:

1. when Facebook scraper requests the page - the _escaped_fragment version should return
2. when user ask the page, he requests the URL with the hash-bang (e.g. "http://www.justanexample.com#!home|mainPage") or without it.
3. when posting to facebook, the link should be as the URL I set ("http://www.justanexample.com#!home|mainPage"), and therefore when the user clicks this URL it will work the same as (2).

but why does Facebook change my URL to the _escaped_fragment?
could someone please explain where is the problem here?

Thanks!

P.S. 
i'm aware of: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8653183/facebook-share-showing-escaped-fragment-url-instead-of-hash-version

and understand it solves the issue, but before using it, I want to first understand what's the cause of this behavior.

Comment: Same question +1. I also set the canonical url tag and og:url tag, but it didn't help. See my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000549/ogurl-tag-in-the-header-is-not-the-same-url-as-rel-canonical-link-in-the-html).