# og:url tag in the header is not the same URL as rel='canonical' link in the html

Tags: url, facebook-opengraph, web-crawler, canonical-link

This is the page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmacondo.tw%2F%23%21%2Fbook%2F50fa1589425b0dc41a000002.

I got the warning "og:url tag in the header is not the same URL as rel='canonical' link in the html".
However, "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" showed that they are the same.

Comment: I need your help.
Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/q/66546478/14467588.